# No resource for my/package in RestRegistry when using Socko Web Server

Tags: scala, sbt, onejar

I am using restful api of socko. When I run my application via `sbt run`, it is ok to run without any problem. However, when I package my application by `one-jar` and run it via `java -jar myapp_2.10-1.0-onejar.jar`, a runtime error occur. So I wonder what the problem with the jar file and my application is. Thank you.

Following is my `sbt about` result:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /path/to/myapp/project
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/path/to/myapp/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.1
[info] The current project is {file:/path/to/myapp/}root 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.3
[info] Available Plugins: com.github.retronym.SbtOneJar
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
```

Following is the runtime error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.netease.cloudstudyindex.httpapi.IndexService.main(IndexService.scala)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No resource for com/pkgpath/httpapi
    at org.mashupbots.socko.infrastructure.ReflectUtil$.getClasses(ReflectUtil.scala:43)
    at org.mashupbots.socko.rest.RestRegistry$$anonfun$3.apply(RestRegistry.scala:127)
    at org.mashupbots.socko.rest.RestRegistry$$anonfun$3.apply(RestRegistry.scala:127)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.mashupbots.socko.rest.RestRegistry$.apply(RestRegistry.scala:127)
    at org.mashupbots.socko.rest.RestRegistry$.apply(RestRegistry.scala:102)
    at com.netease.cloudstudyindex.httpapi.IndexService$.<init>(IndexService.scala:40)
    at com.netease.cloudstudyindex.httpapi.IndexService$.<clinit>(IndexService.scala)
    ... 7 more
```

Following is the part of the result of `jar -tf myapp_2.10-1.0.jar`, where `myapp_2.10-1.0.jar` is in `myapp_2.10-1.0-onejar.jar` generated by `one-jar`:

```
com/pkgpath/httpapi/StatIndexProcessor$$anonfun$paginate$1.class
com/pkgpath/httpapi/LessonSourceIndexRegistration$.class
com/pkgpath/httpapi/RankIndexProcessor$$anonfun$1.class
com/pkgpath/httpapi/StatContent$$anonfun$merge$1.class
com/pkgpath/httpapi/RankIndexProcessor$$anonfun$getRankContents$1.class
com/pkgpath/httpapi/CourseRankIndexResponse$.class
```

Comment: Could you add the runtime error to your question? Do you have any special configuration for one-jar? What version of sbt? It'd be helpful to have `sbt about` attached to your question, too.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski thx. I have updated my post with more information.

Comment: One thought (which is more like shooting in the dark) - do you use any resources to configure the web server? Could you unpack the jar's content to a directory and run the application referencing the directory in CLASSPATH? It could be that the web server doesn't read files out of a jar file. Could you also create a simpler project and publish on github so I could clone the project and give it a shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in socko web server, and I have solved the bug on the following issue in GitHub.

GitHub: [No resource for my/package in RestRegistry](https://github.com/mashupbots/socko/issues/91)